# *ngIf change not detect in template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to show loading for 3 seconds and hide it using `*ngIf`. I'm using angular 8. In my previous projects I didn't have this issue.

Here is my code..

```
//Component.ts
loading = true;
ngOnInit() { 
   setTimeout(()=> {
     this.loading = false;
     console.log(this.loading)
   },3000)
}

//Component.html
<div *ngIf="loading" class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
     <app-loading></app-loading>
</div>
```

loading is being false after 3 seconds, but the change is not detecting in template. May I know why? any suggestion to solve without using ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 4):

The example should work, unless if you use `OnPush` change detection strategy:

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that `changeDetection` has been set to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unwya6)**

```
ngOnInit() {
  let that = this;
  setTimeout(() => {
    that.loading = false;
    console.log(that.loading);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: works fine. Can I have an explanation regarding this?

Comment: Sometimes, within `setTimeout` this instance doesn't work. It's from my personal experience, it doesn't occur with all the versions of Angular.

Comment: Thanks. I just used setTimeout instead of fetching data from a service later. I hope there won't be an issue with my code when fetching data from a service.

Comment: Nope, that won't be any prob, Please accept the answer if this helped

Comment: As I applied your solution in my project, it's still same unless I click on any input box and leave the input tag. After leaving the input tag, the change is being detected. any idea?

Comment: I think it is something else, can you share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: You do not need to add a variable that. The arrow function works fine

Comment: Thank you all. I noticed that `changeDetection` has been set to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`